# Android returns "retrofit.RetrofitError: Only one HTTP method is allowed. Found: PUT and PUT"

Tags: asp.net-web-api

This is my error:

```
D/Retrofit: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sales.updateDeliveryLine: Only one HTTP method is allowed. Found: PUT and PUT.
                                                                                at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.methodError(RestMethodInfo.java:123)
                                                                                at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.parseMethodAnnotations(RestMethodInfo.java:155)
                                                                                at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.init(RestMethodInfo.java:133)
                                                                                at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:294)
                                                                                at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
                                                                                at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
                                                                                at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This is my codes in Android Studio:

```
 @PUT("/salesinsight/GetDeliveryScheduleLineRow/")
        public void updateDeliveryLine(@Path("id") int id, @Body API_DeliveryScheduleLines api_deliveryScheduleLines,
                                       Callback<API_DeliveryScheduleLines> callback);
```

This is my codes in Web Api:

```
// PUT: api/GetDeliveryScheduleLineRow/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutDelivery_Schedule_Lines(int id, Delivery_Schedule_Lines delivery_Schedule_Lines)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != delivery_Schedule_Lines.ID)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(delivery_Schedule_Lines).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!Delivery_Schedule_LinesExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

Every time try to update the error is showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all in your PUT method you are passing id as Integer. But you have not mentioned id in your API path, which is missing. Hope it helps.

```
 @PUT("/salesinsight/GetDeliveryScheduleLineRow/{id}")
    public void updateDeliveryLine(@Path("id") int id, @Body API_DeliveryScheduleLines api_deliveryScheduleLines,
                                   Callback<API_DeliveryScheduleLines> callback);
```

Comment: OHHHH! I forgot about that because I Always use @Query. Thanks mate!